# What is model, view and controller in Android RecyclerView?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, android-recyclerview

I use Model class, Adapter class and Activity while using a RecyclerView in android.

I wanted to know what is model, view and controller here and why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Model is a class that you passed on RecyclerView.Adapter, for example let say we have News.class that has property like title and description.
- Controller is the Activity because it controlls and manipulates what input that inserted into the model data. For example we get data from REST webservice and convert it into list of models.
- View is the RecyclerView.Adapter, because how to display the model data is configured in here. But inside the RecyclerView.Adapter, there is MVC concept too.. There is Model, ViewHolder, and OnBindViewHolder

Comment: You must do a lot of yoga, 'cause I see a great deal of stretching here.

Answer (score 6):

Let's take a very simple example to understand these. Let's say you have to render a list of 1000 people with their names using Recycler View.

**Model**: Put simply, it is the data. In the example, it would be the names of those 1000 people.

**View**: The view is the view that render one data item. That is, the view that renders the name of one user here - it could be a TextView for example.

**Adapter**: The adapter is the controller, and is the backbone to make the model and the view work with each other. It takes in the model, and the view, and then has the logic to display this data model in the views, managing the recycling, updation, etc.

Comment: This seems a lot more sensible to me than the accepted answer.